# A set with positive measure has a point for which every open interval around it has positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$. Let $B \in \mathcal{B}$ be such that
$B \in (-\infty,\infty) $ and $\mu(B) >0$. Give a proof or else give a counter example to the assertion: There exists a point $x \in B$ such that
$$
\mu((x-\delta,x+\delta)) > 0 \:\:\forall \delta >0
$$

**My thoughts**

I think the statement is true, and therefore I am trying to prove it. Clearly, $B$ is an uncountable union of all such intervals. I am trying to find a countable sub cover. I'll appreciate a help.

Comment: Isnt this Lebesgue density thm?

Comment: @Passing By: This is weaker than the Lebesgue density theorem. The Lebesgue density theorem says that $\mu$-almost every $x \in B$ is a point at which $B$ has Lebesgue density $1.$ The analogous result behind this question says that $\mu$-almost every $x \in B$ has the property that $B$ has a positive measure intersection with every open interval containing $x,$ a property that is strictly weaker than even the property of having a positive (symmetric) Lebesgue density at $x.$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $\mathcal{B}$ are the Borel sets (otherwise it doesn't need to be true). Suppose $B\in\mathcal{B}$ is a set such that for all then for all $x\in B\,,$ there exists a $\delta_x>0$ such that $\mu((x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)=0\,.$ Now these sets cover $B$ so since $\mathbb{R}$ is Lindelöf we can extract a countable subbcover $\{(x_k-\delta_k,x_k+\delta_k)\}_k\,,$ hence we have $0\le\mu(B)\le \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\mu(x_k-\delta_k,x_k+\delta_k)=0\,,$ so that $\mu(B)=0\,.$ This proves the contrapositive, proving your claim.

Comment: @Xiao Hmm what property did I use that isn't true for general measures?

Comment: nvm, upvoted I missed one assumption

Comment: @JLA Thank you so much! Indeed, by $\mathcal{B}$, I meant the Borel set.

Comment: I don't see why $B$ has to be a Borel set. The result still holds if $B$ is $\mu$-measurable, and in fact it still holds for an arbitrary subset of the reals if "$B$ has positive $\mu$-measure" is replaced with "$B$ has positive outer $\mu$-measure", at least if $\mu$ isn't pathological enough (and maybe even then -- I'm not sure what the original poster's usage of "measure" might allow).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro What if $\mathcal{B}=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}\,,$ with $\mu(\emptyset)=0\,,\mu(\mathbb{R})=1\,,B=\mathbb{R}$? Then intervals aren't even measurable.

Comment: Fortunately I covered myself by saying "at least if $\mu$ isn't pathological enough"!

Comment: Haha true, though it seems like saying that is enough to cover almost any statement :)